# How to restore folders and files with sublime 3 session file? OSX

Tags: sublimetext3

How I can restore files and folders if I have sublime session file.

inside session file has my missing folders and files. But I dont know how to restore with that file.

Comment: If the session file is in place and valid, Sublime uses it automatically to restore the session. Note however that it only saves the list of files you had open and (in the case of files with unsaved changes when you quit) the content of the file at the time. It's not a wholesale archive of any sort.

Comment: @OdatNurd In Session.sublime_session has content and file names what I need and are missing from my folder. But how it restores them?

Comment: It restores them automatically when you restart Sublime; there isn't any manual step you need to take. That said, if you deleted files from disk while Sublime was closed, when it restarts it will close the tabs for any files that no longer exist, unless there were unsaved changes. If those sorts of files appear in the session, you need to recover them manually as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've been making regular backups (you do, don't you?), you're out of luck. Depending on exactly what you did to delete the directory (I'm assuming through the side bar somehow), If you immediately halt your computer and run a forensic recovery tool on it you might be able to recover some of the lost data if it hasn't been written over, but the sooner you act the better. Good luck!

Comment: OSX i tryed to copy same name folder and it replaced automatically not inserted more files, and lost all folder... I can see files and file contents what I'm missing. But its taking time to copy and paste and beautyfy code.. because code is in one line in Session.sublime_session

Answer (score 0):

Go to your recycle bin, you might be lucky to find them there. Also use the Find button on the Sublime Text Editor itself. Goodluck.

Comment: Recycle bin already had same named folder and new one is not there.